# switch case is ignored in query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query where I set in a switch case. The while loop is going through my rows, and print out 3 randoms rows, where the data in columns `id, weekday, description` is printed out.

The while loop is working and prints out 3 randoms rows. But it seems like the switch case is totally ignored. No matter if I choose wednesday or saturday in the select form, I get a mixed print out of wednesday and saturday.

The purpose of the form, was so I could sort to only see wednesdays and saturdays individually. Does anybody have a clue why that could be?

**HTML**

```
<select name="weekday" class="form-control selectpicker" >
            <option value=" ">Select Weekday</option>
            <option value="alldays">All Days</option>
            <option value="wednesday">Wednesday</option>
            <option value="saturday">Saturday</option>
    </select>
    <form method="post">
       <button class="btn btn-warning">Shuffle</button>
    </form>
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
    $sql = "SELECT id, weekday, description FROM articles";
      switch(isset($_POST['weekday'])){
        case 'wednesday':
            $sql .= " WHERE weekday LIKE 'Wednesday'";
        break;
        case 'saturday':
            $sql .= " WHERE weekday LIKE 'Saturday'";
        break;
      }
      $sql .= " ORDER BY RAND ( ) LIMIT 3";

      $res = $mysqli->query($sql);


    if ($res->num_rows > 0) {
        while($row = $res->fetch_assoc()) {
            echo "article Number: " . $row["id"]. "<br>" .
                 "Weekday: " . $row["weekday"]. "<br>" .
                 "Description: " . $row["description"]. "<br><br>".
                 '<div class="btn btn-warning btn-open-modal" data-id="'.$row["id"].'">See Details '.'</div><br><br>';              
        }
    } else {
    echo "0 results";
    }
?>
```

Comment: You're missing a `break;`. Voting to close as typo.

Comment: Storing weekdays as strings like that is problematic. Why not 0...6 or 1...7 where you pick a convention that matches functions like [`DAYOFWEEK()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_dayofweek)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're switching on if it's set, not on the actual value. Check if it's set, then go into the switch options:

```
if(isset($_POST['weekday'])) {
  switch($_POST['weekday']){
    case 'wednesday':
        $sql .= " WHERE weekday LIKE 'Wednesday'";
    break;
    case 'saturday':
        $sql .= " WHERE weekday LIKE 'Saturday'";
    break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer. I just tried with your code, but I still get a mixed result. It sounds like I have to look for something else than the switch statement then? I could understand if the query was not called at all. The reason why I though the switch case was  ignored, is that the query is called correct, except the switch case.

Comment: In the HTML bring the select inside the form tag.

Comment: Try echoing or dumping along the way. Dump `$_POST` to make sure that weekday exists, and try echoing something inside your switch statements, like add "Checking Wednesday<br>\n" inside of the wednesday case.

Comment: And what Lelio said. :-D

Comment: Shoot.... That did the trick. I just had to set the select inside the form tag. I do not know what I have been thinking. Thank you a lot :)